# GCM + Google Endpoints = No extra server required?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

Im just trying to figure this out; Every tutorial Ive read references a **server** - but I dont really see any need for an additional server if the GCM service runs on Google Endpoints? That in and of itself is the server. My question is whether I would need another server, and if so: why?

My setup is as follows:

- Android Client
- Google Endpoints Server (GCM + Server)

My Android client modifies its data, sends it to server and the server in turns notifies all registered units about the change.

Comment: Please answer for more explanatory; Where do the units register? Or how the android app knows the registered units?

Comment: @YusufKARTAL The Android app registers through the endpoint, and it in turn stores the registered clients in its db.

Comment: So you are not need to another server to send push messages to GCM, you can send messages directly from android app but this will come with vulnerability because of your GCM server key can be taken by others

Comment: @YusufKARTAL Makes sense, but I dont understand how someone could take the server key? Its not inside the Android app.

Comment: I think, your server-key will be on Google Endpoint and endpoint will send messages to clients. As described in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/ there is no need an extra server, they talk about local server to develop on local computer.